# How can I add a custom launcher to favourites in Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome

How can I add a custom launcher to favourites in gnome 3.8. I would like to put a laucher for wow

Answer (score 23):

There are two simple methods:

- Just dragging the application icon to from the list of applications to the left should create the favorite.
- Right clicking any application icon and hit "Add to favorites"

This is more complicated, thus should only be used if you want something done form the terminal:

```
dconf read /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps
```

Will return:

```
['firefox.desktop', 'chromium-browser.desktop', 'evolution.desktop', 'empathy.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'shotwell.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'nautilus.desktop', 'yelp.desktop']
```

Here, you have to treat it as an array, so you must know the name of the application `.desktop` file, ie. `gparted.desktop` for Gparted. Copy the same output and add the one you want.

```
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps "['firefox.desktop', 'gparted.desktop', 'chromium-browser.desktop', 'evolution.desktop', 'empathy.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'shotwell.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'nautilus.desktop', 'yelp.desktop']"
```

This will add Gparted as second element of my favorites. Please be mindful of the syntax that has to be `['application.desktop', 'application.desktop']` with comma and space between each item, and each item between single quotes.

Comment: I'd add that if you are creating your own *.desktop file, you need to put it under ~/.local/share/applications for the favorites to include.

Comment: My .desktop are in ~/.local/share/applications  but it doesn't help

Comment: What puzzles me is that eight years later (2021)... we're still creating cryptic configuration files in a hidden folder and use terminal commands to create a simple shortcut. That's... a **remarkable** UX! (Sarcasm intended.)

Comment: @SePröbläm you don't need to do so, the first two solutions (drag-n-drop and right click) are equivalent to what users expect on any other system.

Comment: @Braiam, Unfortunately the first two solutions don't work if it's a downloaded file somewhere in your user directory. Just drag&dropping it from "Files" onto the bar on the left didn't work.... Got it working, thanks to your detailed explanation, but was surprised how cumbersome that was.

Answer (score 0):

Sombody is deprecating conf files apparently :-) I use the following to edit an existing launcher (you first have to create it somehow using drag-and-drop):

```
dconf read /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps
```

That gets the list of launchers, and then (using the right myapp from the returned list):

```
updatedb; locate myapp.desktop
```

That returns something like:

```
/usr/share/applications/myapp.desktop
```

Then just edit this file.