# How can I modify pinned launcher entries in Gnome Shell? (Example: touchscreen scrolling for Firefox)

Tags: launcher, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

To have working touchscreen scroll functionality in Firefox I made a copy of `firefox.desktop` and put it in `~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop`. I modified the Exec command(s) as suggested:

```
Exec=env MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 firefox %u
```

When I search for Firefox in Gnome Shell and launch it it works, but when I use the launcher it does not. I tried to unpin Firefox and pin it again to the launcher with no effect. I prefer not to modify such system files with root privileges for every user. (There exists a bug in Launchpad to ship it by default.)

How can I modify pinned launcher icons in this case? (I have had no problem doing this on another machine which runs XFCE).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/370596/40581) answer I think I understand how the mechanism works and where it fails in this case.

I now made another copy (`~/.local/share/applications/firefox-custom.desktop`) and replaced `'firefox.desktop'` with `'firefox-custom.desktop'` respectively.

```
$ dconf read /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps
['org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'chromium-browser.desktop', 'org.gnome.Lollypop.desktop', 'mpv.desktop', 'keepassx.desktop', 'org.gnome.Software.desktop', 'vlc.desktop', 'firefox.desktop']
$ dconf write /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps "['org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'chromium-browser.desktop', 'org.gnome.Lollypop.desktop', 'mpv.desktop', 'keepassx.desktop', 'org.gnome.Software.desktop', 'vlc.desktop', 'firefox-custom.desktop']"
```

The launcher item now works as expected.

There is <s>one</s> two problems though:

- When I want to move this item (let's say between nautilus and chromium) a new `'firefox.desktop'` will be created, so I have two Firefox icons in the launcher, which means I have to edit the order in dconf.
- When I launch the application a new icon will be added to the launcher, this is a minor cosmetic problem for me now.

I'm open for better suggestions and solutions here.